# Why I cannot print inside a kernel in Pycuda?

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I have the following start of a code

```
import numpy as np
from pycuda import driver, gpuarray
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.autoinit
MATRIX_SIZE = 3  
matrix_mul_kernel = """
__global__ void Matrix_Mul_Kernel(float *d_a, float *d_b, float *d_c)
{
      int tx = threadIdx.x;
      int ty = threadIdx.y;
      float value = 0;

      int s=5;

      printf("X %d Y \\n",s);
  
      for (int i = 0; i < %(MATRIX_SIZE)s; ++i) {
          float d_a_element = d_a[ty * %(MATRIX_SIZE)s + i];
          float d_b_element = d_b[i * %(MATRIX_SIZE)s + tx];
           value += d_a_element * d_b_element;
       }
 
       d_c[ty * %(MATRIX_SIZE)s + tx] = value;
   } """
  
matrix_mul = matrix_mul_kernel % {'MATRIX_SIZE': MATRIX_SIZE}
  
mod = SourceModule(matrix_mul)
```

The part inside the kernel with printf, if I do `printf("hello");` it goes fine but when trying to print an integer (I was trying to print `tx` and `ty` but never mind, any would be fine) an error appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/PyCuda/9_matrix_mul.py", line 26, in <module>
    matrix_mul = matrix_mul_kernel % {'MATRIX_SIZE': MATRIX_SIZE}
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict
```

Why is this code failing?

Previously when no constant was used, I could print the thread x and y

EDIT:
Even stranger when I do this

```
printf("X %s Y \\n",5);
```

It does not fail but prints this

```
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y 
X {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} Y
```

So apparently no matter the variable it is always interpreted as the dictionary  {'MATRIX_SIZE': 3} therefore the error. The question is why?

what is happening here?

Comment: `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not dict` That error has nothing to do with printing...

Comment: And I am giving it a number, be it the variable `s` or a number. But it interprets it as a dictionary  `{'MATRIX_SIZE': 3}`... Why?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your printf call uses the same string interpolation specifier (%d) used by python's string interpolation.
From Python's documentation:

> When the right argument is a dictionary (or other mapping type), then the formats in the string must include a parenthesised mapping key into that dictionary inserted immediately after the '%' character.

To avoid mixing python and cuda's string interpolation, you can use python's newer string formatting.

```py
matrix_mul = matrix_mul_kernel.format(MATRIX_SIZE=3)
```

Wherever you need MATRIX_SIZE, use `{MATRIX_SIZE}`